# Can not run virtualenv successfully on win10

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

I use python36 and win10, I can install virtualenv successfully. But when I want to activate it, some mistakes have occurred.

```
$pip install virtualenv
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages
$virtualenv venv
Using base prefix 'c:\\users\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36'
New python executable in C:\Users\myvenv\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
  Complete output from command C:\Users\myvenv\venv\Scripts\python.exe - setuptools pip wheel:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkgutil'
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\virtualenv.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 713, in main
symlink=options.symlink)
  File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 945, in create_environment
download=download,
  File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 901, in install_wheel
call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
  File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 797, in call_subprocess
% (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command C:\Users\myvenv\venv\Scripts\python.exe - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1
```

Why is there such a problem?

Comment: You might have a broken "pip". Try to reinstall python to see if problems still remains.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to reinstall, and then the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you don't need to reinstall your python, instead, you can just entry `virtualenv envname --no-setuptools --no-pip --no-wheel` in your cmd line, hope be helpful.